# Difference between field and connection in Graphql ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql, graphql-ruby

I am new to Graphql. For a simple use case, Let's say i have simple model,

```
  class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :comments
  end
```

Below is the code in my graphql query_type.rb

```
PostType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
 #field :comments, types[CommentType]
 #connection :comments, CommentType.connection_type
end
```

Both `field and connection` works for me. But which one is the right way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Connection will help you `paginate` through the list of comments connected to the post with 4 default arguments (first, last, after and before) in the query, whereas field here would return a basic list of `CommentType`

For more on pagination with connection, read up here

http://graphql.org/learn/pagination/